# The smallest integer divisible by 2004

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The smallest positive integer divisible by $2004$ and writing in base ten with the only digits $2$ and $4$ is $222 444$.
What is the next? And the next of the next?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is a problem to attack with congruences and modulo,but it don't know how...

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest or all of them?

Comment: It most definitely isn't the only one. $222444222444$ is another one, and so is $222444222444222444$, etcetera

Comment: the first number is 42244442244 but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: The one after that is $44244424224$, and the one after that is $222444222444$

Comment: Ok but how I can find them?

Comment: The problem asks the first that is next of 222444 and the next of the next.